# Add zeros after each number depending on its position

Tags: php

Input: `5.287.341`

Expected PHP output:

```
5000000
200000
80000
7000
300
40
1
```

Here is the example code for JS:

```
var n = "5.287.341"

var d = n.replace(/\./g,"").split("").reverse();

let string = "";

function padLeft(nr, n, str){
    return nr+Array(n-String(nr).length+1).join(str||'0');
}

for(let i=d.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  string += parseInt(padLeft(d[i] , i+1))+ "\n";
}
console.log(string)
```

Comment: If you want a PHP solution, why is your attempt in JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

```
$n = "5.287.341";
$n = str_replace('.', '', $n);
$count = strlen($n);

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($n); $i++){
    echo $n[$i]; // output the number
    for($j = 0; $j < $count-1; $j++){
        echo "0"; // output zeros
    }
    echo '<br>'; // output line breaks
    $count--;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel like isolating each digit, then multiplying it by 10 to the power of a calculated exponent is most direct.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1SoNL))

```
$string = '5.287.341';

$numbers = preg_split('/\D*/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$exponent = count($numbers) - 1;
foreach ($numbers as $i => $n) {
    $result[] = $n * 10 ** ($exponent - $i);
}
var_export($result);
```

Or

```
$result = [];
$exponentFactor = preg_match_all('/\d/', $string, $numbers) - 1;
foreach ($numbers[0] as $i => $n) {
    $result[] = $n * 10 ** ($exponent - $i);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output from either snippet:

```
array (
  0 => 5000000,
  1 => 200000,
  2 => 80000,
  3 => 7000,
  4 => 300,
  5 => 40,
  6 => 1,
)
```